# ORMLite - Find union of results from two tables

Tags: android, join, ormlite

I have two database-persisted classes in my Android app using ORMLite -

`Contact`:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "contacts")
public class Contact {
    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "_id")
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String first_name;
    @DatabaseField
    private String last_name;
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    ForeignCollection<Phone> phones;
}
```

and `Phone`:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "phones")
public class Phone {
    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "_id")
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String number;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private Contact contact;
}
```

As you can see, a `Contact` has many `Phone`s. What I'm trying to do is generate a query, given a `CharSequence` constraint, to find any Contact whose `first_name`, `last_name`, or `phone.number` matches the constraint.

It's easy enough to get the Contacts who match `first_name` or `last_name`:

```
RuntimeExceptionDao<Contact, Integer> contactsDao = getHelper().getContactsDao();
QueryBuilder<Contact, Integer> contactQb = contactsDao.queryBuilder();
Where contactWhere = contactQb.where();

contactWhere.or(
    contactWhere.like("first_name", "%" + constraint + "%"),
    contactWhere.like("last_name", "%" + constraint + "%")
);

PreparedQuery<Contact> pq = contactQb.prepare();
```

and it's easy enough to get the Contacts who match with a phone number:

```
RuntimeExceptionDao<Contact, Integer> contactsDao = getHelper().getContactsDao();
RuntimeExceptionDao<Phone, Integer> phonesDao = getHelper().getPhonesDao();
QueryBuilder<Contact, Integer> contactQb = contactsDao.queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<Phone, Integer> phoneQb = phonesDao.queryBuilder();

phoneQb.where().like("number", "%" + constraint + "%");
PreparedQuery<Contact> pq = contactQb.join(phoneQb).prepare();
```

But when I try to combine the two, it seems to give me the intersect of the two data sets in the final cursor (which, as you can imagine, is usually 0 results). Is there some way to get the union of the data sets instead?

I'm aware that ORMLite doesn't support `RIGHT JOIN` style queries or returning data from a join table into the results, but that's not what I want - all I need is the list of `Contacts`.

Also note that I'm using a `CursorAdapter`, so (as far as I'm aware) I can't simply make two requests and then join the resulting Arrays together. The data is destined to be displayed in a `ListView`.

**Example**

`contacts` table

```
|   id   |  first_name  |  last_name  |
---------------------------------------
|   10   |  Matthew     |  Smith      |
---------------------------------------
|   21   |  John        |  Smith      |
---------------------------------------
```

`phones` table

```
|   id   |  number      | contact_id  |
---------------------------------------
|   99   |  0444444444  |     10      |
---------------------------------------
|  123   |  0444666666  |     21      |
---------------------------------------
```

A search for "Smith" would return both Contacts. A search for "4444" would return only Matthew Smith, a search for "0666" would return only John Smith, and a search for "044" would return both Contacts.

**EDIT** - Bonus points if the solution returns only unique results - the other side effect of the way I'm currently doing it is that each result is displayed in the `ListView` multiple times - once for its name, and again for each `Phone` it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I try to combine the two, it seems to give me the intersect of the two data sets in the final cursor (which, as you can imagine, is usually 0 results). Is there some way to get the union of the data sets instead?

If I am understanding Matt, what you are trying to do is use the same `constraint` against both the name and the number and show the results that match -- hence the word "union".  I guess having a `nameConstraint` and then a `numberConstraint` is not an option.

Looks like there is a missing feature here.  By default when [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is combining the `WHERE` statements from the query-builder and the joined query-builder, it currently uses `AND`.  I've just added `QueryBuilder.joinOr(...)` and `innerJoinOr(...)` to ORMLite trunk and it will be in version 4.47 that uses `OR`.

Until this release comes out you will have to use the `dao.queryRaw(...)` method and do this as a raw query unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Gray, that sounds like exactly what I need! Do you have any plan or estimate as to when version 4.47 might be released?

Comment: Just added it to my app, and it works perfectly @Gray. I can't speak to any possible performance issues just yet as I only have access to the emulator for now, but the functionality seems spot on. Thanks again!